# Sql Error on an query WHERE id='. $something .' For Public Profile System

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am making a public profile system,like facebook,youtube.....
when user register it create it own profile with his infos and give it a url like `"www.mysite.com/userprofile.php?id=1"` that can bee seen by any one without sign in,any one that visit that url can see the profile,the userprofile.php get data from the database.
here is my code :

```
<?php 
     $id = $_GET["id"];
     $query = ("SELECT username,email FROM table WHERE id=" . $id . " LIMIT 1");
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 echo $row['username']. " - ". $row['email']; }
?>
```

it work when visiting `"www.mysite.com/userprofile.php?id=1"` it get the user info that have the id 1,then echo them, but when i visit `"www.mysite.com/userprofile.php"` it give this sq error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 1' at line 1

even when i delete the "LIMIT 1" it give this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

And one more thing, if any one fixed the error,can you tell me how to make `"www.mysite.com/userprofile.php?id=1"` to `"www.mysite.com/user1"` and how to return a 404 error when the user profile doesn't exist

And any way to secure it from sql injection ?

Thank's Advance :)

Comment: `WHERE id='" . $id . "'` <= that ought to take care of that.

Comment: *"And one more thing, if any one fixed the error,can you tell me how to make "www.mysite.com/userprofile.php?id=1" to "www.mysite.com/user1" and how to return a 404 error when the user profile doesn't exist... And any way to secure it from sql injection ?"* --- `3 for 1`? Had this been Tuesday, I'd say ok. *"And one more thing"* --- actually that's three, not one.

Comment: [**Use (`mysqli`) prepared statements, and nothing but.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) Or PDO equivalent.

Comment: This breaks because you remove the GET parameter from the URL.  userprofile.php?id=1 passes 1 as your parameter, which is used to search your database.  If you plan to pass data through the URL, you have to actually let it pass data through the URL.

Comment: your title has `id='. $something .'` but your code doesn't have that.
use `if(isset($_GET)){...}` before work with user id.
you can shorten url using rewrite rules inyour .htaccess file - search for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate to `/userprofile.php` instead of `/userprofile.php?id=123` you're essentially running this query:

```
SELECT username,email FROM table WHERE id= LIMIT 1
```

Which is an invalid SQL statement. There's a number of ways to fix it, but the easiest would probably be something like this:

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET["id"];
if(!empty($id)) {
    // typecast it for at least a little security
    $query = ("SELECT username,email FROM table WHERE id=" . (int) $id . " LIMIT 1");
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['username']. " - ". $row['email']; }
} else {
    echo "Please provide a user ID."
}
```

This checks if the user ID is set and that it's not empty, and typecasts it to an int before running the query.

With that said, you should really look into [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this kind of thing.

Comment: and I suggest mysqli than PDO